# Parsing between characters using Perl in SAS

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, sas, text-parsing

I am sure this is a simple thing to do but I cannot seem to find any examples or make it past the numerous documentation sources I have been using.

I have a variable in a table (called location) such as: OH_DRT HOME_G4-T7 77 Cafe Entrance

I want to be able to parse this into several columns based on some delimiters. There is variability in my data set so I  thought using perl expressions for pattern matching would be the way to go. I am trying to take that string and break it up into something like this:

| State | Building | Name | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OH | DRT HOME | G4 | T7 Cafe Entrance |
| FL | Cleveland | RG | 03 Back Entry |

I am able to split the first part out

```
Data Mydata;
     Set Int_Data;
     retain re;
     if _N_ = 1 Then re = prxparse("/(\D{2})/");

     if prxmatch(re, location) Then Do
          State= prxposn(re,1,location);
end;
```

It is parsing out any of the other sections I am at a loss for. The only one I have been able to get to work correctly is the State. I assume I should be able to pull anything between two characters.

In my head I should be able to split something like this:
Anything before the first _, anything between the first _ and second _, anything second _ to first -, and then finally anything after the -

Comment: Try SCAN function using _ and - as word delimiters.

Comment: I may have to use Scan or Index I think to get what I am trying to do done. But I believe I should also be able to leverage the regex to get it. So far I have been able to get the State code out and the text between two underscors. This is the what I used for the underscore `Prxparse("(_(.+)_")`

Comment: Sorry I did not get that wanted a RegEx solution.  Looks like you got one from @stevieb

Comment: Please show the actual input for the outputs you are showing.

Answer (score 2):

Are all records exactly the same? If so:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $data = 'OH_DRT HOME_G4-T7 77 Cafe entrance';

my ($state, $building, $name, $desc);

if ($data =~ /^([A-Z]{2})_(.*)_(\w{2})-\w{2}\s+(.*)$/) {
    $state = $1;
    $building = $2;
    $name = $3;
    $desc = $4;
}

print "$state, $building, $name, $desc\n";
```

The regex works as follows:

- Capture two upper-cased letters at the start of the string and put it into `$1`
- Skip an underscore and capture everything until the next underscore and put it into `$2`
- Capture the following two word characters and put them into `$3`
- Skip a hyphen and the following two word characters along with any amount of whitespace, and put the remaining portion of the string into `$4`
- Assign the numbered matches into the more descriptive named variables

Note that if any of the matches/captures fail, all of the named variables will be undefined.

The output of the above is:

```
OH, DRT HOME, G4, 77 Cafe entrance
```

Comment: The records all follow the same pattern so this looks like it is working. Thank you very much. I follow your expression up to `\w{2}\s+(.*)$` I understand selecting the 2 characters and then adding white space. Does the (.*)$ then put the remaining portion in?

Comment: If I wanted to for example change the second delimiter to be either an underscore or a hyphen. I could do that here, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pattern with 4 capture groups, but note that when keeping the following remark into account, it will give `T7 77 Cafe entrance` in the last group.

> and then finally anything after the -

If you want to match anything between the underscores and the `-` you can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) excluding characters to match that you specify.

To not cross newlines, you can add a newline and a carriage return `[^_\r\n]+`

```
^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^-]+)-(.*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `([^_]+)_` Capture 1+ chars other than `_` in group 1 and then match it
- `([^_]+)_` Capture 1+ chars other than `_` in group 2 and then match it
- `([^-]+)-` Capture 1+ chars other than `-` in group 3 and then match it
- `(.*)` Match all after the underscore in group 4

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/46wSoO/1)

If you want `77 Cafe entrance` in group 4:

```
^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^-]+)-[^\s-]*\s*(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1r7xob/1)

Comment: You're first example was correct. I am still working through my data but now I am noticing that my data is not uniform. So I am not sure if this will be something I can do with Regex. the demo you linked was very helpful along with the link. it is looking like some of my locations are missing what would be in group 3 and then dont have the second underscore to reference. I am going to read some more and may end up posting another question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the regex solution works fine. If you wanted a [SCAN](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p0jshdjy2z9zdzn1h7k90u99lyq6.htm) solution.

```
Data WANT(Keep STATE BUILDING NAME DESC);
  Length State $2 Building $50 Name $2 Desc $100; 

  TEST="OH_DRT HOME_G4-T7 77 Cafe Entrance";

  State=scan(test,1,"_");
  Building=scan(test,2,"_");
  temp=scan(test,3,"_");

  Name=scan(temp,1,"-");
  Desc=scan(temp,2,"-");
Run;
```